# SQL Server 2008 copy table with changing physical sequence of fields

Tags: sql-server-2005, ado.net

The task is to copy

```
table1 ( A,C,B )
```

to

```
table2 ( A,B,C )
```

Tables effectively identical, the same fields/constraints just physical sequence of fields is different. Can I do it with standard tools and minimal coding. For bulk copy in this case mapping for each field pair seems to be required.

Comment: Kinda curious, what led you to have a dependency on the column order?

Comment: No real dependency. Just want new fields( table is loaded programmatically from various sources, not normalized for free text search  and additional fields may appear ) not to go the bottom but rather group them with already existing.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a simple

```
insert into table2(A,B,C)
select A,B,C from table1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correctly, you can just copy the table without changes and then change the ordering afterwards.  Change the field order by dragging the column in Design mode in SQL Enterprise Manager.

Comment: My understanding this operation truncates a table.